# How We Decide n in Compound Interest Rate Table When Annual Expenses Increasing After Certain Year?

Tags: interest, compound-interest, economics

I don't understand that, in this question's solution for HEPS9, why we take n as 6. And why we use A/G for SP240 and P/G for HEPS9.

Question:
[image]

Solution:
[image]

Compound Interest Rate Table:
[image]

Comment: Your use of acronyms in the question is making this less readable than it otherwise would be. The textbook you are working from is using particular terminology that may be standard in some contexts, but it's not immediately familiar to me, and possibly many other people reading this question. It isn't clear also that you have attempted any part of this, so answering you is not very different from just fully answering the textbook question, which isn't a great way to use this site. You would get more concrete help by asking the prof / TA for this course.

Comment: To point you in the right direction - the maintenance on HEPS9 starts only in year 4, ending in year 9. How many years does HEPS9 have maintenance for? How would you represent that series of outflows in today's dollars? The maintenance for SP240 is always present from year 1, increasing over time. How long is that series of payments, and how would you represent that in today's dollars?